# 301 Redirect in .htaccess stops working after a few days until i re-save the file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Standard .htaccess file for a Wordpress website. 301 works perfectly (simple redirect from old page slug to a new page). After a few (random) days I re-check the URL and it does not redirect anymore to the new page (tried in different browsers and cleared cache, etc).

All other redirects seem to be fine, expect for this new one which is last line in the file. Yoast is not set to auto-update slug reidrects (i think that feature is only on the premium version anyway).

No other redirect plugins for wordpress are running.

No changes are made to the file (i can see the modified date is the same).

It just returns a 404 after a few days until i log in via FTP and hit save on the file again.

Anyone ever experience this before?

cheers

Comment: Well that the file didn’t change, but then simply re-saving it (I guess you mean a new upload of the version you have locally, to the server?) fixes the issue, sounds rather unlikely. WP itself can re-write the .htaccess file, f.e. if the permalink settings are saved again. Do you have your own edits outside of the `# BEGIN WordPress` / `# END WordPress` comments? Those are what WP uses to identify which section it can overwrite.

Comment: "which is last line in the file" - We'd need to see your `.htaccess` file... if you've used a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (which is what you should be using with WordPress) _after_ the WP "standard" front-controller for a request that does not map to the filesystem then it would never work and _always_ return a 404. If you've used a mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` then it will conflict with mod_rewrite. Ideally you would create such a redirect in WP itself - not `.htaccess`.

Comment: @04FS - not reuploading local version as such, but pretty similar: I just open the file in a text editor directly through cpanel file editor or ftp client and just save the file without editing anything and the issue is fixed. 
I have plenty of edits outside the WP tags (i am experienced with all of this).

Comment: @MrWhite I have about 100 redirects using the simple "Redirect 301" command and all others work fine (for years... this is not a new file). This one redirect is just another standard url same as the others, but happens to be the last one on the list. Also have scanned the file thoroughly to ensure there are no other 301s for the same URL confusing things and there are none.

Comment: @MrWhite Redirects in WP directly are flakey and subject to plugin updates issues etc. I would never trust these long term and always encode them directly in htaccess for all my sites. Last line of my htaccess are just some standard php ini directives - again they have been there for a long time without any issues.

Comment: Do you allow WordPress to modify `.htaccess`? Or have you set perms so that it can't? When this happens again, download the `.htaccess` file and examine the file in a hex editor byte by byte to see if there are any strange bytes / EOL markers that maybe corrupting the file? Although you do state that the last-modified date is the same - so not modified? MD5 hash of the file is the same? Try adding some _comments_ at the end of the file, so that your redirect directive is not the last line of the file.